# Polling the accelerometer/motion sensor in a MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, cocoa, accelerometer, sensors, motion-detection

There is a compiled command line application [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200514010353/http://osxbook.com/software/sms/) that does this.

Is there a Cocoa API to query this data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [SMSLib](http://www.suitable.com/tools/smslib.html), which is an open-source Objective-C library for accessing the sudden motion sensor.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a Cocoa API for the motion sensor. It's only available through calls to IOKit. It's described in [Mac OS X Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321278542).

Comment: A better link is [this one](http://osxbook.com/software/sms/) which is the author's page about the sudden motion sensor with sample code.